# Transfert output from docker container to host's focused window

Tags: docker

I have a C# app running on a container, on the host i have a web page with simple fields. When the app receives data, I want it to fill up the focused field with it.

First idea I have is to simulate keypresses for the host, by having a script run on the host that uses `xdotool` to simulate keypresses, but the problem is that is undermining the docker usefulness, and is only working for hosts with unix runining, `xdotool` installed and the script runining in the background, not even talking about security...

The host is always going to be an Unix system, but the version and packages can change,

Dockerfile:

```dockerfile
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:3.1-alpine

COPY ./publish MyApp/

ENTRYPOINT dotnet MyApp/MyApp.dll
```

I'm also using docker-compose:

```yaml
version: "3.3"

services:
  my-app:
    image: path/to/image
    restart: always

    volumes:
      - /opt/username/configuration/appSettings.json:/CONFIG/appSettings.json
      - /opt/username/logs/:/LOGS/
```

Is there a way to directly output data from a container? Maybe I can mount some volumes and write the data directly somewhere, but i don't know where.